# CSS3 animation event not fired on Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, animation, firefox, dom-events

Trying to set a simple example on how we could use CSS3 animation to catch when an input switch from `enable` to `disable` state, I came to an issue on Firefox.

This is code to replicate issue:

### Demo jsFiddle

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text">
<button>enable/disable INPUT</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd', ':input', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.animationName === "disabled") {
        alert('disabled!')
    } 
    else if (e.originalEvent.animationName === "enabled") {
        alert('enabled!')
    } 
})
```

**CSS:**

```
input:disabled {
    -webkit-animation: disabled 1ms;
    animation: disabled 1ms;
}
@-webkit-keyframes disabled {
    to {
        opacity:inherit;
    }
}
@keyframes disabled {
    to {
        opacity:inherit;
    }
}
input:enabled {
    -webkit-animation: enabled 1ms;
    animation: enabled 1ms;
}
@-webkit-keyframes enabled {
    to {
        opacity:inherit;
    }
}
@keyframes enabled {
    to {
        opacity:inherit;
    }
}
```

**Expected Result:**

Event `animationend`  should be fired when input switch from enable to disable state and vice versa.

**Current behaviour:**

This works on chrome and IE10/11 but unfortunately, Firefox doesn't fire event when input is disabled. It could be expected result but I'm wondering:

### Any way to make Firefox firing `animationend` event on disabled elements?

***PS***: Animation on Firefox for disabled elements works, that's just the bound `animationend` event which is not fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set animation on a sibling element fix it. 
So you can use e.g:

```
.test {position:absolute; left:-9999px;}
input:disabled + .test {    
    animation: disabled 1ms;
    -webkit-animation: disabled 1ms;
}
```

With relevant HTML:

```
<input type="text">
<div class="test"></div>
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkTQ9/)